# Proving openness of a proper subset.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $N\subset M$ be a subspace of $M$.
>
> If for every $S\subset N$, openness of $S$ in $N$ is equivalent to openness of $S$ in $M$, show that $N$ is open in $M$.

So since $S$ is a proper subset, we can not assume $S=N$ and conclude $N$ is open in $M$.

I know how to prove backwards ( i.e $N$ is open, then showing openness of every proper subset of it is equal to the subset being open in $M$ ).

But I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: $\forall x\in N$, $x$ has neighborhood $V_x$ in $M$. Since $V_x \cap N$ is open in $N$, it is also open in $M$. Hence $N = \bigcup_{x\in N}(V_x\cap N)$ is open in $M$.

Comment: @QiyuWen Totally understood, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false.  Take $M=\mathbb{R}$ with topology $\tau=\{(-\infty,a):a \in \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{ \emptyset , \mathbb{R} \}$.  Let $N=(-\infty,0]$.  This has the property that for $S$ properly contained in $N$, $S$ is open in $N$ if and only if $S$ is open in $M$.  However, $N$ is not open in $M$.

Comment: I think $(-1,0]$ is open in $N$, but it's not in $M=\mathbb R$, am I right? If so, this example doesn't have the properties.

Comment: The only open subsets of $N$ are $\emptyset$, $N$, and $(-\infty,a)$ for $a<0$.  If $(-1,0]$ were an open set in $N$, then there would be an open set $U \in \tau$ such that $(-1,0]=U \cap N$.

Comment: There is, $U=(-1,1)\in \mathbb R$ is open and $U\cap N=(-1,0]$.

Comment: The set $(-1,1)$ is open in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  However, $(-1,1)$ is not open in the topology $\tau$ that we defined.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how we can define topology of $\mathbb R$ like this. If we are in Euclidean metric, how can (-1,1) be not open, and not included in the set of open subsets? in other words topology of $\mathbb R$. Do we use a different metric in this example?

Comment: You are correct.  In the Euclidean metric, $(-1,1)$ is an open set.  To define a topology on a set, you don't necessarily need a metric.